# @SessionScoped bean injected as @ManagedProperty of a @ViewScoped acts like @RequestScoped in MyFaces, works fine in Mojarra

Tags: jsf, myfaces, mojarra

Here is my simple example:

`Index.xhtml` in root:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{index.variable}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton action="#{index.submit()}" type="submit"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Its ManagedBean:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Index implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty("#{sessionBean}")
    private SessionBean sessionBean; /*getter&setter*/
    private String variable; /*getter&setter*/

    public void submit() {
        sessionBean.setAsd(variable);
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        try {
            context.redirect("next");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

`/next/index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Check variable</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        #{sessionBean.asd}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`SessionBean.java`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

    private String asd;

    public String getAsd() {
        return asd;
    }

    public void setAsd(String asd) {
        this.asd = asd;
    }
}
```

---

If I use mojarra implementation everything works as expected: after form submitting, user gets redirected to `root/` and see the value that was printed in the form of `index.xhtml`.

But if I use myfaces, `asd` becomes null right after existing form gets submitted. `SessionScoped` bean acts like `RequestScoped`

**Why?**

---

here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
        <!--listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class-->
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

[image]

> Server: Apache Tomcat 7.0.34

**UPDATE**: it works if we change the `ViewScoped` annotation of `Index.java bean` to `RequestScoped` or `SessionScoped`. But why?

Comment: Why do you redirect using the external context? Assuming you use JSF 2, you may just return the next location via `"return /root/index.xhtml;"`. It might be that myfaces and mojarra behave different when you redirect this way.

Comment: You should have either both the MyFaces api+impl JAR files, or the single MyFaces bundle JAR file. You should not have api+impl+bundle JAR files. The bundle file is api+impl bundled in one JAR, so essentially you've currently *two* MyFaces api+impls in your classpath. This is wrong.

Comment: @BalusC yes, this is my bad, but after I change it, this issue still exists.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently have a JSF 2.1 project written with the help of Mojarra. Just for experimenting, I changed the implementation to MyFaces and ran the application only to see issues similar to yours (all my injected @ManagedProperty variables end up null after a POST submit). I switched back to Mojarra and the app runs fine. So, basically something is different in the MyFaces implementation.

A bit of googling led me to this unresolved issue - [MYFACES-3656](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3656). Here's an excerpt from the issue reporter on how to fix the issue:

> If you set the [org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION) to **false**
>   and redeploy the application then everything works as expected.

How does this help? The answer is in the [comments section](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3656?focusedCommentId=13504324&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13504324):

> I think the behavior described is expected (different to say that the
>   behavior described is desired or intentionally done in that way).
>
> What's happening here is in MyFaces serialization is set to true by
>   default (some old lines from JSF 1.0 spec says so, **even if RI does not
>   implement it in this way**). In JSF 2.2 spec, SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION
>   param will be standardized and set to false by default.
>
> Serialization causes that all beans under view scope are in fact
>   "recreated". If the param is set to false, the beans are stored into
>   session and on further requests are used, looking like everything is
>   ok, but that fact is not true because **in a cluster configuration the
>   same application will fail**.
>
> Only the first time the view scope bean is created, the references
>   from managed-property takes effect, but if the bean is
>   serialized/deserialized, the references are not restored back, because
>   on the serialization step, even the application and session scope
>   beans are serialized too.
>
> .....
>
> How to solve it? I haven't found a decent solution to this issue. One
>   could think on just restore the view scope bean and reapply
>   @ManagedProperty annotations or entries found in faces-config.xml, but
>   the problem is the view scope bean still is storing information that
>   shouldn't be there from start (only marking the fields as transient
>   will do the trick). It is possible define an special mode were this
>   hack or some variant is done, but it will be only in myfaces and it
>   cannot be enabled by default.

Similar issue has been reported and replied with the above explanation in this [mailing-list archive](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/201108.mbox/%3CCAGJtJfFsME4VhXEjjdJ6bS76_avPmHz_yh0jLDH8=1P8_RDqGA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Now, since in your case you are not explicitly setting a `STATE_SAVING_METHOD`, it defaults to server. Consequently, `SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION` comes into effect and defaults to true.

I tried your code with MyFaces on Tomcat and set SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION to false and it works. However, in the event, you set the STATE_SAVING_METHOD to *client*, nothing will work and you'll get a view state not found error.