# View scope: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText

Tags: jsf, serialization, jsf-2, view-scope, backing-beans

There is an error each time a button calls an action from the backing-bean.
Only applies to beans with a view scope and I haven't found a way to fix it without regression over other modules in the code.

```
DefaultFacele E   Exiting serializeView - Could not serialize state: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText 
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
```

Or also:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception 
root cause Faces Servlet: ServletException: /jspFiles/jsf/Deployments/editQueue.faces No saved view state could be found for the view identifier /jspFiles/jsf/Deployments/editQueue.faces 
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:205) 
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /jspFiles/jsf/Deployments/editQueue.faces No saved view state could be found for the view identifier:  /jspFiles/jsf/Deployments/editQueue.faces
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute (RestoreViewExecutor.java:128)
```

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>pc_EditQueue</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>pagecode.jspFiles.jsf.deployments.EditQueue</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>queueDeploymentBean</property-name>
    <value>#{queueDeploymentBean}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EditQueue extends PageCodeBase implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
  public String doButtonAddAction() {
    // calls manager (long)
    FacesUtil.setViewMapValue("queueDeploymentBean", queueDeploymentBean);
    return "";
}
```

I read this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425247/sessionscoped-bean-injected-as-managedproperty-of-a-viewscoped-acts-like-req/18481878?s=1%7C1.2366#18481878) to set SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION to false and indeed this solution works for this view scope bean. However this fix comes at a high cost: many existing modules in the application don't work anymore so I cannot use this fix there. Some of the regression observed are:

```
// returns null must be changed with FacesUtil.getSessionMapValue("userId"); 
getSessionScope().get("userId");`

// returns null must be changed with FacesUtil.getViewMapValue("linkerBean");
linkerBean = (Linker) getManagedBean("linkerBean");`

// NPE so must be changed with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(...)
getFacesContext().addMessage(...)`
```

So my questions are:

1. why the NotSerializableException even though the bean implements Serializable ?
2. is there a way to apply the SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION param over only a subset of the beans or not ?
3. is there another solution to have my view scope bean to work (without having to change them to request scope or else) ?

   WebSphere 8.0.0.3,
   Java 1.6.0,
   JSF 2.0,
   RichFaces 4.2.3.Final

Answer (score 4):

> *why the NotSerializableException even though the bean implements Serializable ?*

Not only the bean needs to be serializable, but all of its properties (and all their nested properties etc) must also be serializable. The name of the offending non-serializable class can easily be found in the exception message:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
```

This suggests that you're binding a `<h:inputText>` component to the bean like below:

```
<h:inputText binding="#{bean.fooInput}" ...>
```

```
private UIComponent fooInput;
```

This is indeed illegal when the bean is not in request scope. `UIComponent` instances are request scoped and may not be shared across multiple requests. Moreover, `UIComponent` instances are **not** serializable. Only their state is, but JSF will worry about that all by itself.

You must remove the `fooInput` property and you need to look for a different solution for the problem for which you incorrectly thought that binding the component to a view scoped bean would be the right solution.

- If you intend to access it elsewhere in the view, e.g. `#{bean.fooInput.value}`, then just bind it to the Facelet scope without the need for a bean property:

  ```
  <h:inputText binding="#{fooInput}" ...>
  ```

  It'll be available elsewhere in the same view via `#{fooInput.xxx}`.

  ```
  <h:inputText ... required="#{empty fooInput.value}" />
  ```

  ---
- If you intend to set some component attribute programmatically inside the bean, e.g. `fooInput.setStyleClass("someClass")`, or `fooInput.setDisabled(true)`, then you should be binding the specific attribute in the view instead of the whole component:

  ```
  <h:inputText ... styleClass="#{bean.styleClass}" />
  ...
  <h:inputText ... disabled="#{bean.disabled}" />
  ```

  ---
- If you are absolutely positive that you need to get a hand of whole `UIComponent` instance in the bean for whatever reason, then manually grab it in method local scope instead of binding it:

  ```
  public void someMethod() {
      UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
      UIComponent fooInput = view.findComponent("formId:fooInputId");
      // ...
  }
  ```

  But better ask a question or search for an answer how to solve the concrete problem differently without the need to grab a whole component in the backing bean.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

---

As to the `ViewExpiredException`, this has different grounds which is further elaborated in [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored).